# Retrieving E-Mail from Twitter OAuth2

Tags: go, twitter, twitter-oauth, api-authorization

It seems that the documentation doesn't show the way to retrieve the email (except when using OAuth1).

Here's what I've tried:

```golang
// handler of redirectUrl:
r := resty.New()
r.SetBasicAuth(conf.TWITTER_CLIENTID, conf.TWITTER_CLIENTSECRET)
res, err := r.R().SetBody(map[string]interface{}{
    `code`:          in.Code,
    `grant_type`:    `authorization_code`,
    `client_id`:     conf.TWITTER_CLIENTID,
    `redirect_uri`:  tProvider.RedirectURL,
    `code_verifier`: state[1],
}).Post(`https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token`)
// res.Body will contain, something like this:
/*
{
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":7200,
  "access_token":"Q0V2QUQyN25OLXh1bVdBWUxxxxxxx2NDM1NDk1ODM0NDE6MToxOmF0OjE",
  "scope":"users.read tweet.read"
}
*/
```

if we hit `/2/users/me` using that access token:

```golang
res, err = r.R().
    SetHeader(`Authorization`, `Bearer `+accessToken).
    Get(`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/me`)
// res.Body is:
/*
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
*/
```

but even if it succeed, there's no field that contains email on Twitter's API v2.

The question is, what did I did wrong and or how to retrieve email from OAuth2's access_token? or is it possible to use/convert that access token to retrieve from Twitter API 1.1's endpoint, because I tried that too and it also gives `215 Bad Authentication Data`.

Comment: The email address is not current available in the OAuth 2 authentication scheme, you’ll need to use OAuth 1.0A